# Telegram automatically detects OpenVPN GUI connection, Browser doesn't

Tags: windows-10, vpn, proxy, openvpn, telegram-messenger

I'm using OpenVPN GUI and it successfully connects. Telegram automatically detects the new settings (TCP) but web browsers don't. How can I fix this?

Google Chrome gives the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error and I can't fix it.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Chrome after starting OpenVPN? Or clear all Chrome caches?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. It won't change. I guess it's somehow related to DNS settings. But I'm not a pro so I don't know how to change it and how to reverse it later. I also wonder how Telegram messenger works perfectly while any other apps and programs do not.

Comment: Once the VPN is connected, could you add to your post the output of `ipconfig /all` and `route print`.